# Loop ou Looping?

Tags: debate

Sempre vejo algumas pessoas escreverem **Looping**, e me coça a mão editar, mas vejo que ninguém editou.

Pela definição:

- Loop: laço
- Looping: ação de fazer loops, dar laços, fazer um laço, etc

No contexto **programação**, qual é o correto ?

Comment: Eu só escrevo "loop", 'conjugar verbos' só quando escrevo em inglês mesmo, ou se for um uso de comum na área mesmo, no caso não acho que seja.

Comment: Quando possuo dúvidas sobre as "abrasileirações" das palavras extrangeiras, principalmente as palavras técnicas. Pesquiso um pouco no [Google Acadêmico](https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=looping+programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o&btnG=), [Periódicos CAPES](http://www.periodicos.capes.gov.br/) ou outro de pesquisa acadêmica. E vejo se o meio acadêmico está utilizando com muita frequência estas palavras. O problema da área de programação é que a maioria dos termos são em inglês na sintaxe, sendo até mais fácil utilizar do mesmo modo que a sintaxe. Então normalmente uso o da syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sua definição está corretíssima.

Looping sendo usado como substantivo está errado no inglês e mais ainda em português. Sempre que você ver isso, soque o seu dedo no botão editar!

Comment: Acredito que depois dessa, sem mais !  Rs

Comment: O [priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/looping) nao concorda.

Comment: @BrunoCosta O priberam diz que "looping" em português é uma acrobacia aérea, ***coisa que não deve ser o sentido de nenhuma das perguntas ou respostas deste site.*** O [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loop?q=looping), o [oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/looping) e o [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/looping) redirecionam "looping" para "loop". O [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/looping) mostra que "looping" como substantivo em inglês é algo que faz "loops", já em português, concorda com o priberam.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Mas eu queria fazer um programa para o meu drone fazer looping e agora? Estou a gozar (zoando)  :p.

Comment: @BrunoCosta KKKKKKK